# Problem for importing StringField and URLField

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.html5 import URLField
```

I get this error:

> "FlaskWTFDeprecationWarning: flask_wtf.html5" will be removed in 1.0.  Import directly from "wtforms.fields.html5" and "wtforms.widgets.html5".

so I tried

```
from wtforms.fields.html5 import StringField
from wtforms.widgets.html5 import URLField
```

but doesn't work at all ..

Can somebody help..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your code

```
from wtforms.widgets.html5 import URLInput, Input
```

OR

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm as Form
from wtforms import (StringField, SubmitField)
from wtforms.validators import (DataRequired, Regexp)

# And then create your form with something like the following code

class WhateverForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name*', validators=[
        DataRequired('Name is required'),])
    url = StringField('URL*', validators=[
        DataRequired('URL is required'),
        Regexp('^(http|https):\/\/[\w.\-]+(\.[\w.\-]+)+.*$', 0,
               'URL must be a valid link')])
    submit = SubmitField()
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 widgets and fields are builtin of wtforms since 1.0.4. You should consider importing them from wtforms .To do that use `from wtforms import URLField`.